# Help!!!!!! downgrading iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

i've just upgraded to ios 7.0.2 and i ***haven't saved the shsh blobs*** for my ios 6.1.3 ... iv'e purchased this iphone 2 months ago... can anyone give me shsh?? or how could i restore back to ios 6.1.3.....

I really need help.. iOS 7 is little slow on the iPhone 4. :( Please help guys

Ive tried several things...

last 2 weeks, i had sucessfuly downgraded to ios 6.1.3 but for a jailbreak it bricked my device... and now i'm on iOS 7, i had to update to ios 7...

My iPhone is factory unlocked.. :/

please help guys

Comment: You would have been able to save them using iFaith when you were back on iOS 6.1.3, because you have an A4 device. You also would have been able to actually downgrade (again, because you have an A4 device) if you had the SHSH blobs.

Answer (score 7):

An SHSH Blob is device specific and meant to be like an individual fingerprint or ID number so that no two devices share the same identifier.

It uses the ECID (Exclusive Chip ID) of your device, along with a challenge key, as part of the authentication process with Apple. Thus anyone providing their own to you wont help you.

Answer (score -1):

I hate to tell you this, but you cannot save the `SHSH blobs` for your iPhone when it was back on `iOS 6.1.3`, even if that was a matter of 40 mins ago. It's gone, done and dusted.

When the `baseband` was upgraded with `iOS 7.0.2`, you lost that ability, and there isn't anything anyone can do.

Sorry, you're just going to have to live with it and stop updating it until a new jailbreak comes out that you can use, but even then, you probably won't be able to downgrade.

Downgrades are usually only available on the same series of a firmware, not cross-series. The only thing that would get you an iPhone with 6.1.3 back on there, would be if you damaged your phone and had insurance to cover it. Though, that's not even a guarantee. I'm sorry to say, but you're stuck where you are for now.

Comment: -1 The baseband, jailbreaking, and iOS 7 has nothing to do with your ability to downgrade. It's an iPhone 4 (with an A4 chip), so if he had SHSH blobs, he would be actually be able to downgrade to iOS 6.1.3.

Comment: Baseband has a direct correlation to the firmware. The baseband needs to be able to be "hacked" so the shsh blobs can be retrieved so he can even downgrade. And there's no proof that he can downgrade at this stare anyway. Having SHSH blobs from 1.0 doesn't mean you can downgrade all the way to 1.0.

Comment: This is what the baseband is: http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Baseband_Device
This is what SHSH is: http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/SHSH They are independent of each other. You can grab SHSH blobs from Apple for currently-signed firmware so long as you know the ECID of the device.

Comment: In fact, I did this myself this morning with my old iPhone 4S. It doesn't even have to be plugged in to your computer. You just give Apple the ECID, and they give you back an SHSH blob.